# iTunes Won't Load Alternate Path Library Files When Changed in Preferences/Advanced

Tags: itunes, libraries

I recently built a new computer and just reinstalled iTunes. As with my previous setup, Windows 10 is on one SSD and all of my files are on another. That includes my iTunes library files and all of my music files.

The problem I'm having is even when I change the "iTunes Media folder location" in the Advanced Preferences, iTunes will not load that library. I have restarted iTunes. I have restarted my computer. I've closed iTunes, deleted the default library files, and when I start iTunes back up it just creates new blank library files as if it's starting for the first time.

Besides it creating new library files in the default location after I delete them, when I replace the default library files in the default location with my existing one, it loads up my data no problem. During all of this, if I open Advanced Preferences, it tells me it's looking at the alternate location I specified.

I'm running Windows 10 and iTunes 12.9.2.6. And no, I have not changed the name of the library file.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I had to do was hold Shift while starting iTunes. This brings up a dialog box allowing you to choose what library to open or create a new one. When I pointed it to my existing library on my external drive, it worked fine. Also, after closing iTunes, it opens fine now with a regular start (not holding Shift). I hope this helps someone.